# SchemaValidation brings ClassCastException and OutOfMemoryError in MTOM file upload

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, java-metro-framework, mtom

I'm created file upload webservice:

```
@SchemaValidation
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.ws.server.ExchangeEndpoint")
public class ExchangeEndpoint {

@Override
public String uploadDocument(long residentId, String fileName, String mimeType, DataHandler data) {

    try {
        StreamingDataHandler dh = (StreamingDataHandler) data;  //it cast exception
```

Here is interface:

```
@WebService
@StreamingAttachment(parseEagerly = true, memoryThreshold = 4194304L)
@MTOM
public interface ExchangeEndpoint {
    @WebMethod String uploadDocument(@XmlElement(name = "residentId",required = true) long residentId,
                                 @XmlElement(name = "fileName",required = true) String fileName,
                                 @XmlElement(name = "mimeType",required = true) String mimeType,
                                 @XmlElement(name = "data",required = true) @XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream") DataHandler data);
```

And it cast ClassCastException exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.activation.DataHandler cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.ws.developer.StreamingDataHandler
```

**But when I remove @SchemaValidation annotation all works fine!!!**

So why @SchemaValidation corrupts DataHandler object?

When I try to upload big file >300mb I get OutOfMemoryError:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space  at org.jvnet.staxex.ByteArrayOutputStreamEx.readFrom(ByteArrayOutputStreamEx.java:75) at org.jvnet.staxex.Base64Data.get(Base64Data.java:331)
```

And also **without @SchemaValidation all works fine!!!**

Comment: Try increasing the memory allocated to the java machine and see if you are able to validate a bigger attachment.

Comment: We had this confusing issue as well with apache cxf 3.2.2. I am surprised that it has so few votes. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

This is a well known problem.
Without schema validation, your file can be transfered as a binary attachment streamed one chunk at a time so that no memory problem appear.
If you add schema validation, the file must be coded base64 and inlined in your xml message ; this cause memory problem when the file is too large.
All jaxws implementation that I know work this way.

You have exactely the same problem for the same reason if you add digital signature to your webservice.

I have unfortunately no solution to that problem.